# ServerAlias influences $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?

Tags: php

Basically i have a classic vhost with:

```
ServerName www.site.com
ServerAlias site.com
```

I would like to have always `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www.site.com';` even when someone open `site.com`

Is this possible?

Comment: @Amber how if use forwarding with htaccess ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, PHP does not know anything about ServerName, ServerAlias etc.

The proper solution is configuring your webserver to redirect from all your alias domains to the main domain. That's also a good thing from a SEO point of view.

You can do this e.g. using `mod_rewrite`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you have additional domains, simply setup a separate VirtualHost for them which redirects to your main domain:

```
<VirtualHost ...>
        ServerName site2.com
        ServerAlias *.site2.com
        Redirect / http://www.site.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually best practice to redirect www to the null domain, or vice verse.  You can do that by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This way, `site.com` will redirect to `www.site.com`, and you'll only see `www.site.com` in your `SERVER_NAME` variable.